# AJAX fails to set Cookies on browser after CORS request. Set-Cookie header is present only in FireFox, not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies, cross-domain

I am sending an AJAX request using JQuery to a NodeJS server, which SHOULD be setting cookies back to the client without a problem, but it's NOT. I can see the `Set-Cookie` headers in the response, yet skimming the `document.cookie` string does NOT contain my cookies!! If anyone could take a look over this code, I would much appreciate it.

Request Code:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "https://my-site/mailcamp",
   contentType: "application/json",
   dataType: "json",
   processData:false,
   data: JSON.stringify(reqBody),
   success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);   
   },
   xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
   crossDomain: true,
})
```

Server Response:

```
app.use('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://www.texashunterproducts.com");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, x-access-token, x-user-pathway, x-mongo-key, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  next();
});

router.route('/mailcamp')
    .post(async (req, res, next) => {
        try { 
            res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [`texaspopup=true`]);
            res.cookie("texcookienowpopupnow", "trueasheck")
            res.send("Send me dem cookiez");
        } catch(err) { next(err) }
    })
```

I'm just NOT getting this in document.cookie. I have some strange inconsistencies:

I can clearly see the `Set-Cookie` response header in FireFox Network Tab:

[image]
[image]

However, it is completely missing in Chrome!

[image]

I'm not able to find the cookie when parsing `document.cookie` at all. I've copy+pasted the contents of `document.cookie` and can not find my key/value pair using `ctrl+f`. Why? What's going on here? It shouldn't be hidden because I'm not adding `Httponly` markers on the cookie, and I'm sending it directly to the domain that I am querying from.

Comment: Browser may have a user-set preference not to set cookies.

Comment: Certainly possible. What I'm really confused about is why I can clearly see `Request Cookies` in the FireFox DevTools -- meaning cookies must have been set -- yet they are NOT visible in `document.cookie`. As you can see from the server code, I am not putting any secure flags on them which would make them inaccessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a foolish problem. It's a third party cookie. While it is set by an external domain, it can't be read by the receiver via doc.cookies, only when browsing to the domain from which the cookie was sent. I ended up using code from this source to set a cookie locally within the client, as well as sending the subsequent request to accomplish the server action:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework

Comment: Why is the set-cookie header not shown in the response header list in chrome?

Comment: @where Looks like it's a security issue with newer versions of chrome called "Site Isolation"  that can be disabled.
I haven't tested this issue any further, but you can check out these articles:

https://techdoma.in/how-to-fix-chrome-not-showing-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests-in-network-pane/
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/site-isolation